# Docker CLI on Windows: config.json path?

Tags: configuration, docker-cli

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/registry_history/ , some experimental features of the **Docker CLI** can be enabled by editing the [config.json](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) file.

But, on Windows, where is the **config.json** file located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the **config.json** file in:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker-CE 25.0.4, on Windows

Navigate to:
C:\ProgramData\Docker\

Create a folder called "config"

Within the config folder, create a text file called "daemon.json"

Ensure it is not daemon.json.txt !!! Show your file extensions...

Then you can add content like:

```
{
    "insecure-registries": ["172.29.229.8:5000"],
    "allow-nondistributable-artifacts": ["172.29.229.8:5000"]
}
```